# Cannot attach dependencies for module-info

Tags: dependencies, jakarta-mail, javac

I am trying to deal converting automatic modules to explicit modules and I am not very familiar with java through the command line.

I am currently trying to do this with javax.mail but I am having depenency issues when compiling.
I am using the following command in cmd:

```
javac -p javax.mail -d classes module-info.java
```

I get the following error:

```
module-info.java:5: error: module not found: java.activation
requires transitive java.activation;
```

I have tried to add the javax.activation-1.2.0.jar and the same as an extracted jar. I've also tried adding

```
--module-path classes
```

and

```
--class-path classes
```

This was along with trying

```
--add-modules java.activation
```

and

```
--add-modules javax.activation
```

Nothing seems to work and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to add a module-info.java to JavaMail?  Or are you trying to use JavaMail in a project of your own with it's module-info.java?  Note that if you build JavaMail from source using JDK 9+ it will include its own module-info.java; it's just not part of the standard release yet.

Comment: I am trying to add a module-info.java to JavaMail to make it an explicite module. Are you saying JavaMail doesn't need this as it already has it's own module-info.java?

Comment: Yes, in the [source code](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/javamail/blob/master/mailapi/src/main/java/module-info.java).

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I had an older version. If only it were always so easy.